# PHP syntax in $exif issue

Tags: php, syntax, exif

Hello would like to know how can I get this syntax correct.

I got this code from:
    http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

code below:

```
<?php

$exif = exif_read_data('tests/test2.jpg', 0, true);
echo "test2.jpg:<br />\n";
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
?>
```

now I want to add a line which actualy gives you the image name. test1.jpg etcs from php array.

```
test/<?=$prod['image_url'] ?>
```

like this

```
<?php

$exif = exif_read_data('test/<?=$prod['image_url'] ?>', 0, true);
echo "test2.jpg:<br />\n";
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
?>
```

replacing

```
tests/test2.jpg
```

with

```
test/<?=$prod['image_url'] ?>
```

but the syntax is incorrect. Please suggest how it can be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

modify

```
exif_read_data('test/<?=$prod['image_url'] ?>', 0, true);
```

to

```
exif_read_data('test/' . $prod['image_url'], 0, true);
```

Full code

```
$exif = exif_read_data('test/' . $prod['image_url'], 0, true);
echo "test2.jpg:<br />\n";
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Error reason : You can't put php tag inside another php tag

Answer (score 0):

ouch. ok, try this. It allows you to use the $prod['image_url'] in the string $filename and then pass $filename to the exif_read_data function.

```
<?php

$filename = sprintf("tests/%s",$prod['image_url']);

$exif = exif_read_data($filename, 0, true);

printf("%s<br/>",$filename);

foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
?>
```